# Can I use Nginx as web server without using any WSGI library like uWSGI or Gunicorn in Flask?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

As far as I know, WSGI is a interface for web server and python web application to communicate each other.

One thing that I'm curious about is whether Nginx can be WSGI compatible.

If it can, it doesn't seem necessary to use intermediate WSGI server between Nginx and python web application requiring additional HTTP request(or maybe UNIX socket).

I just want to use only Nginx and Flask application without Werkzeug's builtin development server.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx is a web server. It serves static files, however it cannot execute and host Python application.So, you need gateway between nginx and python where WSGI is an option.

Comment: So, you mean, there must be at least one WSGI compatible application server such as uWSGI or Gunicorn to run python web application with WSGI?

Comment: Yes. But is there any specific reason you don't want to use gateway?